# literal does not match format string in 12c Oracle

Tags: oracle, sql-insert, ora-01861

I am working on oracle 12c but when I execute my query, I'm getting

> `literal does not match format string`

Below is my Query :

```
INSERT INTO customers
  (customer_id, ciams_uid, title, fname, lname, email,
   dob, store_num, store_name, mobilephone, is_medical_card,
   scheme_number, status_code, create_date_time, last_update_time,
   is_locked, ciams_token, store_phone)
VALUES
  (1, '5', 'test', 'test', 'test', 'test@gmail.com',
   '2014-07-07', '5555555', 'test', '7845125487', 0,
   4555, 'klkl', '2014-07-01', '2014-07-07',
   0, 'dsdssd', '46464646');
```

I want to insert the values.

Comment: Most likely one (or more) of your columns are datetime/timestamps, and you are only passing in a date literal with no time component.

Comment: You are passing string literals for dates. Precede the strings with the keyword `DATE` to make them date literals. E.g. `DATE '2014-07-07'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you need to format your date values

such as `date'2014-07-07'` or `to_date('2014-07-07','yyyy-mm-dd')`

Answer (score 1):

You are providing strings in places where `DATE` datatypes are needed.

Oracle sees this and attempts to coerce your string '2014-07-07' into a `DATE` datatype.
This is done implicitly using your current setting for `NLS_DATE_FORMAT`.

Oracle docs for [NLS_DATE_FORMAT](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-FC23EEEE-AA9F-4B3C-8CBB-888C9C0CA27F.htm#REFRN10119)

You should not rely on the setting of `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` for implicit date conversions.
Rather, explicitly include either a `DATE` literal, a `TIMESTAMP` literal, or a `TO_DATE` function call.

Oracle docs for [datetime literals](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF51062)

Examples:

```
SELECT DATE'2014-07-07' FROM DUAL;
SELECT TIMESTAMP'2014-07-07 00:00:00' FROM DUAL;
SELECT TO_DATE('2014-07-07','YYYY-MM-DD') FROM DUAL;
```